# jQuery :hover selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to change the :hover color of the menu from the color picker.

This is not working ? I need to do it without .hover() function.

```
$( ".mega-menu li:hover > a" ).css( "background-color", "#000" );
```

Comment: Can't you do it with just plain CSS ?

Comment: agree..very simple with css...no script needed

Comment: To change it from css is simple. I'm trying to change it by the color picker.

Comment: @charlietfl thank you for your reply guys. Do you have any suggestions how can I do this. Thnx.

Comment: if it is only for hover condition ...could create a style tag and add to head. Otherwise use hover function

Comment: I'm trying to explain that I dont want to use mouseover. I need to change from some other input. for example when I insert a hex code "#fff" into an text input, I want to set this value in CSS as the background color of the hover state. PS: This is not a dublicate subject.